# Array lost its object after some time

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, xmpp, openfire

I creating chat app, i add messages to `arrayChat` :

```
-(void)msgRecevied:(NSMutableDictionary *)messageContent
{
    NSString *m = [messageContent objectForKey:kMsg];
    [messageContent setObject:[m substituteEmoticons] forKey:kMsg];
    self.arrayTemp = messageContent;

    [self.arrayChat addObject:self.arrayTemp];

    [_tblChat reloadData];

    if(self.arrayChat.count > 1){

        NSIndexPath *topIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self.arrayChat.count-1
                                                       inSection:0];

        [self.tblChat scrollToRowAtIndexPath:topIndexPath
                            atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle
                                    animated:YES];
    }
}
```

but after some time when i put my device for some time, after it when i send messages, it add object to `arrayChat` but it not loaded in tableView, and i reload table it show me last object it lost from `arrayChat`.

I declare `arrayChat` like :

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{

    NSMutableArray *arrayChat;
}
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *arrayChat;
```

and i also `@synthesize arrayTemp;`

Any mistake here ?

**EDIT**

I add my `arrayChat` to other class and i declare that class to `Appdelegate` i used that class to access that array on app, and it's working, but problem occur when i add object to array but it not reloading my table at once, I 'm enlarging my chat view on button that time my last added object to array is show.

here is my code when im enlarging view :

```
-(IBAction)onClickViewLarge:(id)sender{

    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGFloat screenWidth  = screenRect.size.width;
    CGFloat screenHeight  = screenRect.size.height;


    if (!isShow) {

        [_btnOpen setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ico_expand"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{

            if(screenHeight >= 736)
                self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,66 , screenWidth, screenHeight - 66);
            else if (screenHeight >= 667)
                self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,60 , screenWidth, screenHeight - 60);
            else if (screenHeight >= 568)
                self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,51 , screenWidth, screenHeight - 51);
            else if (screenHeight >= 480)
                self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,43 , screenWidth, screenHeight - 43);
        }];
        isShow = true;

    } else {
        [_btnOpen setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ico_open"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
            self.view.frame = CGRectMake(screenWidth - 250,screenHeight - 450 , 250, 450);
        }];
        isShow = false;
    }

    if([app.Glb.arrayChat count] > 0)
    {
        [self.tblChat reloadData];

        NSIndexPath *topIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:app.Glb.arrayChat.count-1
                                                       inSection:0];

        [self.tblChat scrollToRowAtIndexPath:topIndexPath
                            atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle
                                    animated:YES];
    }

}
```

How this is solve ?

Comment: I think the issue is with global arrayTemp object. Try declaring it inside your msgRecevied method

Comment: not effect anything.

Comment: Is your arrayTemp is also strong? If not set it to strong. I think its setting to nil after some time.

Comment: yes,, its :strong,nonatomic

Comment: did u initialise your `self.arrayChat` ?

Comment: yes ... im initialise self.arrayChat

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with the `arrayTemp` object which you declare globally. Each time you are overwriting its value and so you are overwriting the content of arrayChat itself. Try declaring it local to your method like this

```
-(void)msgRecevied:(NSMutableDictionary *)messageContent
{
    NSString *m = [messageContent objectForKey:kMsg];
    [messageContent setObject:[m substituteEmoticons] forKey:kMsg];
    NSMutableDictionary *arrayTemp = [messageContent mutableCopy];

    [self.arrayChat addObject:arrayTemp];

    [_tblChat reloadData];

    if(self.arrayChat.count > 1){

        NSIndexPath *topIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self.arrayChat.count-1
                                                       inSection:0];

        [self.tblChat scrollToRowAtIndexPath:topIndexPath
                            atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle
                                    animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: my code worked some time but it lost after some time when i do other thingg in app,,,,

Comment: You are getting last object in the array only once or n number of times?

Comment: is anything that is need to be done for thread safe of arrayChat ?

Comment: i declare my array to other class and i used it... it working but i have to reload table for two times.